# How to use pointers for arrays of arrays of char?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program that fills an array of array of `char`. How to use pointers instead of passing the whole array of array of `char` into the function argument.

See the following code:

```c
#define COLUMN 20
#define ROW 10

void fillArray(char array[][COLUMN], char c)
{
    int i = 0, j;
    for (; i < ROW; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
            array[i][j] = c;
}

int main()
{
    char array[ROW][COLUMN];
    fillArray(array, '*');
}
```

Is there a way to use pointers instead of passing the whole array of array of char into first argument of '`fillArray`' function?

Comment: Notice that in *this very case* you do not even need to write a function. `memset(array, '*', sizeof(array)); ` is sufficient in **`main`**. (does not work within the function because it does not have an array but a pointer, but you can use `memset(array, '*', COLUMN * ROW);`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there a way to use pointers*

Yes, by doing it exactly as you do it.  :-)

This declaration

```
void fillArray(char array[][COLUMN], char c)
```

in fact is identical to

```
void fillArray(char (*array)[COLUMN], char c)
```

The 2nd version tells you that `array` is defined as a pointer to an array of `COLUMN` `char`s.

The general rule is:

> When an array is passed into a function then it is decayed to a pointer to its 1st element. <sup>*1</sup>

So when in `main()` you pass `array` to `fillArray()` then `array` is decayed to a pointer a `char[COLUMN]`, to a `char(*)[COLUMN]`.

---

<sup>*1 Conversely this means that in C it is not possible to pass  a "*whole array*" directly to a function. This only can be achieved by wrapping the array into a `struct`.</sup>